# Glassfish jdbc/database lookup failed

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, glassfish, web.xml

I hope I am not asking a duplicate question just because I was unable to find an answer.
I am getting this error:

*javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/osclassDB' in SerialContext*

This is what I did: I set up a **JDBC Connection Pool** and a **JDBC Resource** pointing to that pool (both in Glassfish).

Then I told my **web.xml** that there is a JDBC Resource:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/osclassDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>                
</resource-ref>
```

And then I tried using that resource in a **Servlet:**

```
  Connection connection = null;

  try {        
     InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
     //Context dbContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

     DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/osclassDB");
     connection = dataSource.getConnection();

     if (connection == null) {
         throw new SQLException("Error establishing connection!");
     }
     // some queries here
  } 
  // catch and finally close connection
```

But when I call the `Servlet` it throws me the `NamingException` and tells me that the `Lookup failed for 'jdbc/osclassDB' in SerialContext`

**What am I doing wrong here?** is it the web.xml? did I miss something?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem:

**1st** by adding a *sun-web.xml* that links the *resource reference* from the *web.xml* to an actual *jndi-name* (the one I setup on Glassfish). Normally, that shouldn't be necessary (says Oracle) but I did it anyways **[Edit:** as it turns out, it is really not necessary! **]**

**2nd** I left out the "*jdbc*". In the *servlet*, the *web.xml* and the *sun-web.xml* it is now just called "osclassDB" (my resource name) instead of "jdbc/osclassDB"

now it looks like this:

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>osclassDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>                
</resource-ref>
```

**sun-web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>osclassDB</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>osclassDB</jndi-name>  
</resource-ref>
```

**in the servlet**

```
Context dbContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) dbContext.lookup("osclassDB");
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

**[Edit:]** the *sun-web.xml* is really not necessary