# Get a jdbc connection from pool created in glassfish 4

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, glassfish-4.1

I created in glassfish4.1 console a new connection pool. I named it "MyPool" and successfully pinged.
Now I expect to use in my web-app something like:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = dontknow.getFromPool("MyPool");
```

but I did not find any example on how to retrieve it. Is there any sample to copy from?

Comment: You probably want to look at the [Java Persistence API (JPA)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm). You can also perform a JNDI lookup to get resources including JDBC datasources or JMS resources. There are details on doing that [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21138123/212224)

Comment: [Here's another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1916124/212224)

Comment: @Mike This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection pool must be linked ad jdbc resource, namely "jdbc/MyResource". Then:

```
javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/MyResource");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```